# How create transparent window in mac?

Tags: macos

I am new to MAC development. I want to create a window with transparent. If i put the image or any control, the control only should display and window should not display and that window move horizontally or vertically within screen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [Apple's sample project RoundTransparentWindow](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/RoundTransparentWindow/Introduction/Intro.html).

Comment: How to move window dynamically within screen resolution.

Comment: Do you mean [setFrame:display:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWindow/setFrame:display:) ? If not, please open a new question.